# Rendering a unicode character correctly in TextView?

Tags: android

I'm getting a string sent to me from a server (my app is running on android). One of the characters is a unicode symbol which is a musical note. I take the response from the server in a String, then hand it directly to a TextView. This is what should appear:

```
♫
```

but instead I see just a block (kinda looks like):

```
[]
```

when I print the string to logcat, I see:

```
â«
```

I'm not sure how to get TextView to display the character correctly. I tried this:

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(text).toString());
```

but it's still rendering out the block. What's the right way to do this?

Thanks

-------------------- Update -----------------------------

I tried just creating a webpage with the character in it, then pointing the system browser to the page (on my nexus one). Same render issue, looks like the glyph for that character just does not exist?:

```
<html>
  <body>
    &#x266B;
    <br />
    &#9835;
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First, the block is also known as the "Missing character character".  And I think you're right about the missing glyph.  I wonder if there's some way to check the font[s] available...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try looking into this package:

[org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)

It has the ability to unescapeHtml and unescapeXml that contains unicode characters. However, Android is using the Droid font, and I don't think the musical note character exists in that font. You'll have to somehow include a font that does include that character with your app, then use StringEscapeUtils to convert from what the server sends to what you want to display.

Comment: Argh yeah just missing the glyph, oh well yeah guess I'll have to package my own font if I want.