# How to display Arabic characters using unicodes in android?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android.i am prepared one app, it support multiple languages.I want to display `Arabic` characters.i found one site for Unicode's,

```
http://www.unics.uni-hannover.de/nhtcapri/arabic-alphabet.html
```

I used following code for display Arabic letters,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         sb.append("\u0649");
         tv.setText(sb.toString());
```

It is working fine,but showing square box.Please help me.

Comment: What is the type of `tv`? TextView?

Comment: Might be a font issue. See also this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109182/rendering-a-unicode-character-correctly-in-textview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android 2.1 and Android 2.2(support) don't have Proper implementation for the Arabic font.
Android 3.x(from Honeycomb) supports Arabic completely. 
Unicode Characters for Arabic you will find in this [PDF](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFB50.pdf)
or
you can fallow the procedure given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7962813/1213738).

Answer (score 0):

There's no native support for Arabic font till Honeycomb.

Comment: yes, its should work automatically in ICS (4.0.3) because its after Honeycomb (3.0)